# MySQL - Conditional Insert/Update of row based on 2 non-UNIQUE values

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I'm looking to log the inventory of different items in different locations.

Ideally, I will just reference the item id and location id and specify the quantity in a table.

### Sample Data

```
id  |  location_id  |  item_id  | qty
1   |  1            | 1         | 10
2   |  1            | 2         | 12
3   |  1            | 3         | 12
4   |  2            | 1         | 5
5   |  2            | 3         | 5
6   |  3            | 2         | 1
```

I am looking to write a query that will check the see if a row exists based on the location and item ids and either update or insert a row as necessary.

I've tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO `inventory` (`location_id`, `item_id`, `qty`)
VALUES('4', '300', '1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `qty` = `qty` + 1
```

but the problem is that it requires the key values to be primary/unique in each column.

Any ideas on how i'd achieve this in a single statement? Do i need to use an IF?

Comment: In each? Surely it's a composite key (location_id,item_id) !?!

Comment: alter table schema and then use REPLACE or ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: Thanks guys - it was indeed supposed to be setup as a compound key.

Answer (score 0):

First write query check whether you have that entry

```
$sql = "select * from `inventory` where qty = '4'";
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
then query for update 
}
else
{
query for insert
}
```